# TkInter: how can I pass a numeric value to specify the color?

Tags: python, tkinter

how can I assign a numeric value instead of a string to specify the color of my button ? What the exact syntax ?

```
 button = tk.Button(itemFrame, text="", bg="red", width=10, command=callback)
```

i.e  `bg = #FF0000`

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two general ways to specify colors in Tkinter.

1. You can use a string specifying the proportion of red, green, and blue in hexadecimal digits.
2. You can also use any locally defined standard color name

> #rgb Four bits per color
>
> #rrggbb  Eight bits per color
>
> #rrrgggbbb   Twelve bits per color

**The format should be string**

```
bg='#FF0000'

and not bg=#FF0000
```